# Eventlet.timeout doesn't raise exception but stops the flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, timeout, eventlet

If I try to give a timeout to a code to execute in the following manner:

```
t = eventlet.Timeout(20)
try:
    <code>
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    t.cancel()
```

Something is raised and the flow stops. Although, if I don't specify the Exception to be handle, like:

```
except:
    pass
```

It doesn't halt the execution. The only explanation I can find for that is that `eventlet.Timeout` doesn't raise an exception that is from class `Exception` so it is not captured on my `except` clause.

So how can I catch it?